# PackageCloud unable to install global packages

Tags: npm, packagecloud.io

i was previously using package cloud for work;
i ran `curl https://MASTER_TOKEN_GOES_HERE:@packagecloud.io/install/repositories/{privateRepoName}/script.node.sh | bash` to set up packagecloud

now that i am not using package cloud i am unable to install any global packages as its only looking for packages within that package cloud repo;

when i try, i get something like: `npm ERR! 404  '@aws-amplify/cli@https://packagecloud.io/{privateRepoName}/npm/@aws-amplify/cli/-/cli-4.45.2.tgz' is not in the npm registry.`

how do i remove packagecloud from my computer locally.